# SharePoint 2013 Content Search Web Part tasks aggregation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-search-web-part, sharepoint-search

Is it possible to display current user's tasks that are assigned to groups he belongs to using a Content Search Web Part ?

Thanks.